# Error occurs when use a QScrollArea

Tags: qt

```
#include <QtCore>
#include <QtGui>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QScrollArea>
#include <QScrollBar>
#include <QFileDialog>
#include"QDebug"
#include<math.h>
#include<QApplication>
QScrollArea* scrollarea = new QScrollArea;

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
QMainWindow(parent),
ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
ui->setupUi(this);
ui->label->setBackgroundRole(QPalette::Base);
ui->label->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Ignored, QSizePolicy::Ignored);
ui->label->setScaledContents(true);

scrollarea->setBackgroundRole(QPalette::Dark);
scrollarea->setWidget(ui->label);
setCentralWidget(scrollarea);
QImage img("D:\\picture.jpg");
ui->label->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(img));
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
delete ui;
}
```

i am newbie in Qtcreator.
i try to add scroll bar to label. but when i run, it occurs an error:
QWidget: Must construct a QApplication before a QPaintDevice
how should i do to fix this

Comment: Show us your `main()`.

Comment: #include "mainwindow.h"
    #include <QApplication>

    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();
    
    return a.exec();
   }
this is my main()

Answer (score 1):

```
QScrollArea* scrollarea = new QScrollArea;
```

You are constructing a global `QScrollArea` before `QApplication` is created.  Make it a member variable of `MainWindow`.

Comment: Then please accept (it's the tick next to my answer), otherwise people searching with the same problem as you will see your question but think that it hasn't been solved.